# how to create a bar chart by counting values by date for a variable?

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, bar-chart

My data looks like this.

[image]

The following code  creates the bar chart (below).

```
# counts per month

df %>% 
  group_by(date) %>% 
  summarize(dep_delay= mean(dep_delay)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = as.factor(month(date,label = TRUE)),
             y = dep_delay)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity') +
  theme_bw()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,1400,200))+
  labs(title="Departure delays in Newark airport per month in 2013", 
       x="", y = "number of delays")
```

However, the correct counts should be as follows

```
df_w_delays %>% group_by(month=month(date)) %>% count()

  month     n
   <dbl> <int>
 1     1  1035
 2     2   941
 3     3  1239
 4     4  1159
 5     5  1240
 6     6  1257
 7     7  1277
 8     8  1100
 9     9   702
10    10   880
11    11   861
12    12  1315
```

So the bar chart counts do not look correct.

[image]

I have tried changing this line, summarize(dep_delay= mean(dep_delay)) to
summarize(dep_delay= n(dep_delay)) and summarize(dep_delay= count(dep_delay)) which gives errors in summarize().

```
Error in `summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `dep_delay = n(dep_delay)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: date = 2013-01-01.
Caused by error in `n()`:
! unused argument (dep_delay)

Error in `summarize()`:
! Problem while computing `dep_delay = count(dep_delay)`.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: date = 2013-01-01.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'count' applied to an object of class "c('double', 'numeric')"
```

Can someone explain why mean() works in summarise but count() does not? how can I show row counts by month in the bar chart?

Comment: Please, provide us with `df_w_delays ` data.

Comment: `count()` is a low-helper function. In other words, it is a shortcut. A shortcut to `summarise(n = n())` so you don't use `count()` inside  `summary()`